# We have too much free speech

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tag-synonyms

The tag [free-speech](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/free-speech) has no usage guidance and is used on just 7 questions.

It appears to be at best a subset of questions about [freedom-of-speech](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/freedom-of-speech), with 80 questions and some guidance.

[free-speech](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/free-speech) should be synonymised to [freedom-of-speech](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/freedom-of-speech).

Answer (score 4):

Agree that [free-speech](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/free-speech) should be a synonym. The usual [guidance](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70710/what-are-tag-synonyms-and-merged-tags-how-do-they-work) is that synonyms eventually be merged. In this case, "free speech" is a popular lay term, so I suspect we might want to maintain the synonym for quite a while.